# Select using the value of a column

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table of items, identified by their unique ID, along with some properties.

To keep the table readable, the property is always stored in the column 'prop_value' and its type is stored in the column 'prop_type'

**To simplify, I have used only three properties, in fact, there is 12.**

```
+----+-------------+-------------+
+ ID + prop_type   +  prop_value +
+----+-------------+-------------+
+ 1  +    prop1    +   foo       +
+----+-------------+-------------+
+ 1  +    prop3    +   toto      +
+----+-------------+-------------+
+ 3  +    prop2    +  lorem      +
+----+-------------+-------------+
```

The aim is to get all the properties for an item in a sigle row, a result such as:

```
+----+-------------+-------------+-------------+
+ ID +     prop1   +    prop2    +      prop3  +
+----+-------------+-------------+-------------+
+ 1  +    foo      +   NULL      +    toto     +
+----+-------------+-------------+-------------+
+ 2  +    NULL     +   lorem     +    NULL     +
+----+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

At the beginning, I used a very ugly solution:

```
select prop1 from myTable where id = 1
select prop2 from myTable where id = 1
...
```

Now that I am scaling this up, it is taking forever, and I would like to make it in one query.

I have tried something like:

```
select a.prop_value, b.prop_value, c.prop_value from myTable a FULL JOIN myTable b FULL JOIN myTable c ...
```

But it feels like I'm am going into something way more complicated than it needs to be.

Is there a compact solution to achieve this? Thank you for your help.

Comment: Always state your Oracle version (such as 11.1, 11.2, etc.) - if you don't know, run `select * from v$version`. That is important in most cases. In this case: if your version is 11.1 or above, you can use the `pivot` operator. In earlier versions you can always use "manual" pivoting, Ollie has already shown how in his/her Answer.

Comment: It even more complicated than this, it's a custom integration of an Oracle database by an industrial software vendor (AspenTech's SQLPlus)

Answer (score 3):

Use a `PIVOT`:

```
SELECT *
FROM   your_table
PIVOT  ( MAX( prop_value ) FOR prop_type IN (
  'prop1' AS prop1,
  'prop2' AS prop2,
  'prop3' AS prop3
) )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use some conditional logic, such as a `CASE` statement, along with an aggregate function to get the result:

```
select Id,
  max(case when prop_type = 'prop1' then prop_value end) as Prop1,
  max(case when prop_type = 'prop2' then prop_value end) as Prop2,
  max(case when prop_type = 'prop3' then prop_value end) as Prop3
from myTable
group by Id;
```

This type of query pivots the row values into columns.